# if statment with var actual text

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a little help with Access VBA. 
I need to define a variable in a form from user input and, depending on the choice, create an `If` statement with that var.

Something like this:

```
'defining var
if text.value = 12 then
ST = "If Not HasValue(Forms!co.Theme) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin) Then"
else
ST = "If Not HasValue(Forms!co.message) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.fone) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin) Then"
end if
```

Then, in another form, call the var and "inject" the var in the statement...

```
ST            'here i like to have the actual text in the var so i can build the statement
else
end if
```

The `HasValue` function is in a module and works well, also I declare the var `Public` so I can call it from any form I need to:

```
Option Compare Database
public ST as string
```

Am I shooting the moon, or is it real easy and I just can't see it?

Comment: maybe a type issue is 12 a string or a float or what?

Comment: 12 was just an example... it will be text pull from textboxs

Comment: From my interpretation, you want to 'generate code' on-the-fly and then execute it.  If so, you can't do that as your code is compiled when you start running the app.

Comment: well the all idea was to have a single  function that can analyze multiple scenarios and then "adapt" the 1st check of the statement... guess it's too much.

Comment: From your example, since you are not really using the User Input as an executable instruction, you could simply write code for all of the conditions you could encounter, then execute the one associated with the user input. I assume the form controls you want to reference are on Form 2 (the one you will call)?

Comment: they are, the problem is that the controls change according with the var.. if the user chose 1st option will have "X" controls,if chose 2nd will have "Y", and i have about 35 different combos of a total of 25 different controls to check,this is why i wanna a single instruction so i dont have to write the same code 35 times...

Comment: No offense intended, but that comment clarifies where you're at in learning about coding...  The "_single instruction so you don't have to write the same code 35 times_" is called a "**subroutine**", or `Sub` for short.  The very essence of coding is _to automate, not to repeat_; theoretically, you should never have to type identical code more than once, never mind 35 times.  That being said, if you ever did need something more than once, copy & pasting takes 2 keystrokes.

Comment: To add to what @ashleedawg is saying, sometimes when I have been faced with needing to generate *many* lines of code, but varying a name or such, I have often used a combination of Word or Excel. i.e. In Excel I paste all the names as rows, then use various formulas to generate the lines of code.There are many tricks to generate code when a loop will not work.

Comment: Another favorite trick of mine, when I first started learning VBA, was to [Record Macro to generate code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) of the task I needed to automate (as closely as possibly) and then anaylze the VBA code generated for the macro, experimenting with changes, and Googling everything, [revising the code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros) to fit my needs.

Comment: Create a function called (eg) `AnyMissing` which accepts an array of controls, then store that array in your ST variable.  Assuming all the other cases follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the result:

```
Dim b As Boolean

If text.value = 12 Then
    b = Not HasValue(Forms!co.Theme) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin)
Else
    b = Not HasValue(Forms!co.message) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.fone) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin)
End If
```

and then use it :

```
If b Then
    '...
Else
    '...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you *could* write code on the fly, but it's complicated and can cause a lot of problems, and I can guarantee that there's another way to accomplish what you need to do.

Without seeing more of your code & the form I can't say for sure, but perhaps some nested `If`'s would be better, something like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit 'always try to use this option too (for unrelated reasons!)

Public myFlag As Boolean
```

*...and then...*

```
If Text.Value = 12 Then myFlag = True Else myFlag = False
```

*...and then...*

```
If myFlag Then
    If Not HasValue(Forms!co.Theme) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin) Then
        '…_do something here_…
    Else
        '…_do something here_…
    End If
Else
    If Not HasValue(Forms!co.Message) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.fone) Or Not HasValue(Forms!co.cxlogin) Then
        '…_do something here_…
    Else
        '…_do something here_…
    End If
End If
```

Also, is `HasValue` just checking if a control on the form has a value?  If so, another way to accomplish the same thing would be something like:

```
If myFlag Then
    If Nz(Forms!co.Theme, "") = "" Or Nz(Forms!co.cxlogin, "") = "" Then
        '…_do something here_…
    Else
        '…_do something here_…
    End If
Else
    If Nz(Forms!co.Message, "") = "" Or Nz(Forms!co.fone, "") = "" Or Nz(Forms!co.cxlogin, "") = "" Then
        '…_do something here_…
    Else
        '…_do something here_…
    End If
End If
```